# Detect background battery restriction

Tags: android, settings, battery

[image]Under battery settings for a given app, a user can restrict background battery usage.  Is there a way to programmatically determine if the user has turned on this setting for my app?  Note:  This is not the same as Battery optimization...the feature just arrived in Android P.